# entity framework - select TOP of both tables in a JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My model is (simplified version):

Album (ID, Name)

Picture (ID, AlbumID, File). Please note the FK to Albums.

I want to write a query to return the most recent albums (top 10), but just the first 5 pictures of each albums.

I wrote:
`_context.Albums.Include("Pictures").Take(10).ToList();`

In this case, SQL will return the top 10 albums, but ALL pictures for these albums. However in some cases each album may have hundreds of pictures, so I would like a query to limit the number of pictures to 5, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but maybe something like that.

```
_context.Albums.Select(m => new {
     album = m,
     pictures = m.Pictures.Take(5)
}).Take(10);
```